# Task.Run loop with external parameters are changed by loop

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task

I have this code (simplified) to process an array of parameters on 100 different parallel threads, but the variables x and y gets changed by the loop within the threads while are used in threads. If I run the function with 1 thread then it's working.

I also tried to put the parameters in a ConcurrentBag and making the loop with foreach but the same result, the parameters gets mixed in threads.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
var listConcurentBag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
int nThreadCount = 0;

for (x=0; x<1000; x++)
  for (y=0; y<1000; y++)
  {
     int x1=x;
     int y2=y;

     Task t = Task.Run(() =>
     {         
        int param1=x1;
        int param2=y2;

        // some calculations with param1 and param2

        listConcurentBag.Add(result);
     }); // tasks

     tasks.Add(t);
     nThreadCount++;

   if (nThreadCount == 100) // after 100 threads started, wait
   {
       nThreadCount = 0;
       Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
       tasks.Clear();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is this intentional, or a bug? `for (y=0; x<1000; y++)`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it was just a typo here in stackoverflow

Comment: You seem to be doing a lot of work here for no reason - tasks use the thread pool by default so even if you try to buffer by 100 tasks you're only executing as many as the thread pool can deliver. There's no tangible execution or memory usage benefit from doing this buffering.

Comment: "the variables x and y gets changed by the loop within the threads while are used in threads" - not in this code that you've presented. You need to provide a [mcve] if you want a clear and direct answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity The performance increase is very noticeable with this method! from 1 thread to 120 the performance is about 1000% better!

Comment: @MarioM - What's the performance like when you use 4 or 8 threads? And by the way, you're not starting 100 threads, you're starting 100 tasks, and they only use what the thread pool gives them. You're only setting the **maximum** - not the actual number of threads.

Comment: @Enigmativity the default thread pool size is much higher than 100, it's about 250 threads/core. for 4-8 threads the performance is increase is about 100-200%

Comment: @MarioM - I just checked - it's 1_000. Interestingly, though, I just wrote a test which pumped out 100_000 tasks and recorded the distinct `ManagedThreadId` and it only got to 57 - even with a small `Thread.Sleep(10)` to delay the completion of the task.

Comment: @Enigmativity in the latest .NET versions it's dynamic based on the available system resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a suggestion for an alternative implementation, that you may or may not find suitable for your needs. Instead of processing the tasks in batches of 100
you could express the nested-for loops as a single enumerable, and then feed it to the build-in method [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) to do the work of parallelism.

```
private IEnumerable<(int, int)> GetNestedFor()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 1000; y++)
        {
            yield return (x, y); // return a ValueTuple<int, int>
        }
    }
}

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
var options = new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 100 };
Parallel.ForEach(GetNestedFor(), options, item =>
{
    int param1 = item.Item1;
    int param2 = item.Item2;
    Console.WriteLine($"Processing ({param1}, {param2})");
    Thread.Sleep(100); // Simulate some work
});
```

Output:

> Processing (0, 1)
>   Processing (0, 2)
>   Processing (0, 0)
>   Processing (0, 3)
>   ...
>   Processing (0, 998)
>   Processing (0, 997)
>   Processing (0, 999)
>   Processing (1, 0)
>   Processing (1, 1)
>   ...
>   Processing (999, 999)
>   Processing (999, 998)

Comment: thanks, but I have 3 parameters, I just simplified the function for stackoverflow, is there a way to use something else than tuple?

Comment: Yes, you can use a custom class if you want. You can also use a Tuple with 3 elements, like this: `ValueTuple<int, int, int>`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this

Answer (score 2):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
var query =
    from x in Observable.Range(0, 1000)
    from y in Observable.Range(0, 1000)
    from r in Observable.Start(() => GetResult(x,  y))
    select new { x, y, r };

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Buffer(100)
        .Subscribe(results =>
        {
            /* do something with each buffered list of results */
        });
```

Now this isn't strictly doing the same as your current code, but it is giving you blocks of 100 results as soon as they are available using the maximum capacity of the thread-pool.

You could change it to set the concurrency like this:

```
var query =
    from x in Observable.Range(0, 1000)
    from y in Observable.Range(0, 1000)
    select Observable.Start(() => new { x, y, r = GetResult(x,  y) });

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .Merge(maxConcurrent: 100) // limit to 100 threads
        .Buffer(count: 100) // produce 100 results at a time
        .Subscribe(results =>
        {
            /* do something with the list of results */
        });
```

If you want to stop the code before it naturally completes just call `subscription.Dispose();`.

Rx does tend to produce much cleaner code, IMHO.

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity! Two questions about your first code sample. 1) What is the difference between `from r in Observable.Start(...` and `from r in Task.Run(...`? 2) I noticed that the query is asynchronous. How do you await the subscription?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - There's an overload in Rx that turns `Task.Run` into an observable. You get more control with `Observable.Start` as you can set the scheduler.

Comment: I wonder if the performance is not slower with this method? because of the high level of implementation

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - If you want you can do `var results = await query.ToArray();` The `.ToArray()` is only there because calling `await` on an observable only returns the last value produced.

Comment: @MarioM - Measure it. Use `Stopwatch` to measure properly.

Comment: Thanks @Enigmativity. I am trying to make `await` work with no luck. I want to print all results of subscription `.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine)`, but the program ends before all results are printed. I don't really need it to run asynchronously (with await). Blocking is fine. Is there a way to block the current thread until the end of parallel processing?

Comment: I found the solution regarding the first code sample. `query.Wait()` does the trick. I am struggling with the second code sample though. It doesn't want to wait.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You can do `.Wait()`, but do `query.ToArray().Wait()` to get all of the results.

Comment: @Enigmativity I don't want the results. I have the `IDisposable subscription` for handling the results. I just want the waiting.

Comment: If you have both a subscription and a `.Wait()` then you have two subscriptions that each run the observable. You should only have one.

Comment: Then I need a way to wait for the subscription. I have a way of cancelling it (by disposing the disposable), but I have no way of waiting it.

Comment: Sure you do. Just use a `Do`/`Wait` combo rather than a `Subscribe`.